# How to work with face recognition in Java?

Tags: java, face-recognition

Please explain me any face recognition library in Java.
I'm unable to find any library for face recognition in Java if any link is there please send me that link.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow.  This site is mainly aimed at answering specific questions to do with development.  It is not google.  Please do some research (for example: google "computer vision java" or something like that).

Comment: Try to search with similar wording (detection, etc): https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is a good library for face detection applications.

There are some examples of face detection applications.
Link: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

Comment: Please Give me full beginners tutorial for it. because i'm a newbie of this. Please suggest me.

Comment: There is a sample, but they use sbt (Scala build tool for building it). However you can build sample program using Apache Maven. Link to sample: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#running-sbt-samples

Answer (score 0):

You could give [faint](http://faint.sourceforge.net/) a try. If that doesn't satisfy you check also [here](http://bit.ly/1qGA9Kx).

Comment: Give me any tutorial related to it if you have.